# foreach по данным, которые содержатся внутри $wall

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как работать с данными, которые содержатся внутри $wall?

В частности интересует цикл `foreach`

```
$wall = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=durov");
$wall = json_decode($wall);
```

Comment: Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Перебирал массив foreach($wall as $row) { echo $row['id']; } выдает ошибку

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($wall);` после `$wall = json_decode($wall); ` возможно структура станет вам более ясной.

Comment: По крайней мере, скажите trueб чтобы был массив `$wall = json_decode($wall,true);`

Comment: @Дима может $row->id ? Обычно JSON`ом все-таки объекты передаются, а не массивы

Answer (score 1):

```
$wall = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=durov");
$wall = json_decode($wall);
if($wall) {
    foreach($wall as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->response; // вам приходят из json объекты, var_dump($wall) в помощь
    }
}
```

### Дополнение

`json_decode()` возвращет объект если в json строке `{}` или индексный массив, если в строке `[]`